# How to transfer a file from iPhone to computer when there is no Internet?

Tags: iphone, usb, file-transfer

I have a word doc saved as an attachment in my inbox. I can read it using my iPhone 4S, but I can't edit it, and anyway, I want to edit it on my MacBook Pro. But there is (was) no Internet where I was, and so I couldn't access the file on my computer. Is there any way to transfer the file from my phone to computer using USB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can transfer the document to a general-purpose app that "knows" about files (like [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-iphone/id306277111?mt=8), [Air Sharing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing-for-iphone-ipod/id289943355?mt=8), or iBooks), you should be able to access it from the file-handling dialog from within iTunes.

Most computers can create an ad-hoc WiFi network; using this, you'd use a network-sharing app (like [Air Sharing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing-for-iphone-ipod/id289943355?mt=8)) to mount a disk from your iPhone and transfer the files to your computer.

Comment: Wow. This is a pretty complex procedure for such a simple task.

Answer (score 4):

The [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) program can read files from iOS devices through USB and get them to your mac in most cases.